# Getting pairwise comparison for the prediction() function in R (equivalent to margins variable_name, pwcompare(effects) from stata

Tags: r, prediction

I am new to R and trying to get predicted probabilities after a logistic regression and then do a pairwise comparison. I  want to do the same as the margins command in stata. I have therefore used the prediction() package from Thomas Leeper. However, I can't figure out how to da a pairwise comparison of the predicted probabilities. I would prefer the pariwise comparison to be done based on the predicted probabilities from prediction() and not emmeans(), because they give slightly different results in my real data (not the toy data). So, I would really appreciate any help!

Below, I have inserted some toy data - I hope it meets the requirements for a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise let me know.

```
library(margins)

M_W <- sample(x = c("W", "M"), size  = 100, replace = TRUE)
M_W <- factor(M_W)
value <- sample(x = 0:1, size  = 100, replace = TRUE)
xx <- sample(x = 1:10, size  = 100, replace = TRUE)
dataframe <- data.frame("value" = value, "M_W" = M_W, "xx" = xx)
model <- glm(value ~ M_W + xx, data = dataframe, family = "binomial")
summary(model)
pp <- prediction(model, at = list(M_W = c("M", "W")))
summary(pp)
```

Comment: emmeans() by default weights things equally when computing marginal means. I think margins() maybe uses some other kind of weighting. But other weighting options are available in emmeans() if that is the concern. See the vignette on messy data in the emmeans package.

Comment: Hi Russ. Thanks for the answer. Sorry for not clarifying that, but I have tried the different specifications of the "weights" argument, but that did no do it. However, specifiyg weights = "prop" in emmeans() enables me to reproduce statas margins for OLS, so perhaps it has somethig to do with factors in logistic regression?